# Замена конструкторов статическим методом генерации

Tags: java, конструктор

Прочел что можно заменить конструктор статическим методом генерации.

У меня в классе есть два приватных поля

```
private String one,
и 
private String two,
```

и нужно создать два конструктора разных конструктора для этих разных переменных.
компилятор ругается на одинаковую сигнатуру.

можете подсказать, как это можно решить с помощью статического метода генерации.

Comment: эти переменные тоже должны быть статическими

Comment: исправил на статические

Comment: теперь ошибки не должно быть

Comment: а как это можно переписать с помощью статического метода генерации?

Comment: public static getInstance(String o, String t){
   one=o;
   two =t;
}

Comment: @Padawan эти поля могут быть и не static

Comment: @Санаев переменные не должны быть статическими. Более того, статические переменные должны использоваться в очень ограниченных случаях. На сколько я понимаю, автору надо создавать объекты с разными значениями полей, а не задавать значения статических полей класса.  
@Padawan, уберите `static` и создайте приватный конструктор и два статических метода `fromOne(String one)` и `fromTwo(String two)`.  
Ну, и конечно, можно использовать builder, как в ответе @DaysLikeThis

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
public class User {

private String username;
private String email;

private User(String username, String email) {
    this.username = username;
    this.email = email;
}

public static User buildWithEmail(String email){
    return new User(null, email);
}

public static User buildWithUsername(String username){
    return new User(username, null);
}

}
```

Answer (score 5):

Возможно стоит использовать шаблон проектирования builder. В отдельном классе задаем поля one, two с помощью сеттеров и затем методом build будет создаваться требуемый экземпляр класса

Например:

```
public class MyClassNameBuilder {
     private String one;
     private String two;

     public MyClassNameBuilder withOne(String one) {
          this.one = one;
          return this;
     }

     public MyClassNameBuilder withTwo(String two) {
          this.two = two;
          return this;
     }

     public MyClassName build() {
          return new MyClassName() ... используем one, two в конструкторе или с помощью сетеров
     }
}
```

Comment: автор же просил использовать статические методы.

Comment: @Санаев я предложил другой вариант решения поставленной задачи

Answer (score 2):

Могу предложить 4 варианта:

1. Изменение статических полей класса в статическом блоке инициализации.
2. Конструктор (String, String)
3. Конструктор (String, Enum)
4. Инициализация двойными скобками

> Стоит отметить, что **Double Brace** можно считать хорошей
>   альтернативой шаблону проектирования **Builder**, но увлекаться в его
>   применении не стоит ([Подробнее...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1958636/what-is-double-brace-initialization-in-java))

~ 5. Можете капнуть в сторону вложенных классов.

**Java Code (Main.java)**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] arg){
        Example example1 = new Example("one", Example.Method.ONE);
        Example example2 = new Example("one", "two");
        Example example3 = new Example(){{
            setOne("one");
            setTwo("two");
        }};
    }
}
```

**Java Code (Example.java)**

```
public class Example {
    private static String one;
    private static String two;

    static {
        one = "one";
        two = "two";
    }

    public enum Method{
        ONE,
        TWO
    }

    Example(){
        // PASS
    }

    Example(String text, Method method){
        if (method == Method.ONE){
            Example.two = text;
        }
        else if (method == Method.TWO){
            Example.one = text;
        }
        else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("...");
        }
    }

    Example(String one, String two){
        Example.one = one;
        Example.two = two;
    }

    public static void setOne(String one) {
        Example.one = one;
    }

    public static String getOne() {
        return one;
    }

    public static void setTwo(String two) {
        Example.two = two;
    }

    public static String getTwo() {
        return two;
    }
}
```